# How do I add routes to a VPC's default/main route table with Ansible ec2_vpc_route_table?

Tags: amazon-ec2, routes, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm having real trouble adding additional routes to a newly created VPC's default Route Table in a NAT scenario using Ansible and the ec2_vpc_route_table module.  The related excerpts from my Playbook are...

**Creating the VPC**

```
- name: Create Production VPC
  ec2_vpc:
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws.secret_key }}"
    state: present
    cidr_block: 10.0.0.0/16
    resource_tags: { "Name":"Production" }
    internet_gateway: yes
    dns_hostnames: yes
    dns_support: yes
    subnets: 
      - cidr: 10.0.10.0/24
        resource_tags: { "Name":"A - NAT" }
      - cidr: 10.0.20.0/24
        resource_tags: { "Name":"B - Public" }
      - cidr: 10.0.30.0/24
        resource_tags: { "Name":"C - Private" }
    wait: yes
  register: prod_vpc
```

**Gather facts and append new routes**

```
- name: Gather default Route Table facts
  ec2_vpc_route_table_facts:
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    filters:
      vpc-id: "{{ prod_vpc.vpc.id }}"
  register: vpc_default_route

- name: Add NAT routes
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws.secret_key }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ prod_vpc.vpc.id }}"
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    route_table_id: "{{ vpc_default_route.route_tables[0].id }}"
    lookup: id
    tags:
      Name: NAT
    subnets: 
      - '10.0.10.0/24'
    routes:
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gateway_id: igw
```

So first off, I tried to include the creation of the routes within the `ec2_vpc` task, but that actually ended up creating a second Route Table rather than including the routes in the default table.

So first off, **why does a second table get created instead of adding the routes to the default?**

Because including it in the vpc creation wasn't working I fell back on the above, which just identifies the default, or `main` Route Table. The problem now is that when I try to use `ec2_vpc_route_table` to add the NAT route, Ansible fails with the following error...

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to associate subnets for route table RouteTable:rtb-..., error: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code><Message>cannot disassociate the main route table association rtbassoc-...</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>...</RequestID></Response>"}
```

That error makes it sound like, dispite the fact I'm explicitly providing `route_table_id`, and `lookup: id`, that it's not updating the existing table, but it's basically recreating it, trying to delete the original (which is the `main` route table) in the process.

**How can I append additional routes to an existing `main` route table?**

So far the only workaround I've been able to use is to call the EC2 CLI via the `command: ...` method, but that's obviously not ideal.

We're on `Ansible 2.3.0 (devel 14a2757116)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are some [notes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_vpc.py#L585) in the source code stating that _boto can't set the main table yet_. Not sure if it is still a valid statement.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks for pointing that out, that explains a bit. Trouble is, I'm not really trying to delete it, I'm trying to append to it, but it seems the behaviour is to delete and rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to update the main route table by looking it up and then using the `route_table_id` to modify it.

```
- name: Lookup VPC facts
  ec2_vpc_net_facts:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Name": "{{ vpc_name }}"
  register: vpc_group

- name: Create vgw 
  ec2_vpc_vgw:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_group.vpcs[0].id }}"
    name: "{{ vpc_name }}"
    type: ipsec.1
    state: present
    validate_certs: no
  register: vpc_vgw

- name: Create igw 
  ec2_vpc_igw:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_group.vpcs[0].id }}"
    state: present
    validate_certs: no
  register: igw 

- name: Lookup route tables
  ec2_vpc_route_table_facts:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      vpc-id: "{{ vpc_group.vpcs[0].id }}"
  register: vpc_route_tables

- name: Setup route tables
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_group.vpcs[0].id }}"
    lookup: id
    purge_subnets: false
    route_table_id: "{{ vpc_route_tables.route_tables[0].id }}"
    subnets: "{{ subnet_ids }}"
    routes:
      - dest: 10.0.0.0/8
        gateway_id: "{{ vpc_vgw.vgw.id }}"
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gateway_id: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
```

Note: You need to disable purging the subnets otherwise you'll get an error when ansible tries to remove the default subnet association from the main route_table.

Comment: You've looked up the route tables, and then called on the first one found, using: `route_table_id: "{{ vpc_route_tables.route_tables[0].id }}"`. But if that returns more than one route table, you're essentially choosing whichever random route table happened to be first in the results. I'm trying to figure out for myself how to specify that I want the _main_ route table. In the play to lookup the route tables, I tried setting an additional filter like this: `"association.main": true`, but it didn't work. It works as a filter on the command line, but it ain't working in the Ansible module. Hmm.

Comment: @ToddWalton it appears to work if i quote `true` like this `"association.main": "true"`

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_route_table_module.html#options

> Look up route table by either tags or by route table ID. Non-unique tag lookup will fail. **If no tags are specifed then no lookup for an existing route table is performed and a new route table will be created.** To change tags of a route table or delete a route table, you must look up by id.

Try `lookup: tag` instead of `lookup: id`.
That should work.